# Can't allocate memory to read a file in Go

Tags: go, out-of-memory

I'm new to Go and therefore may not understand some things. Now I want to rewrite my Python code to merge dbf files into a single one, but when reading large dbf files of about 1.5 GB I get the error:

> runtime: out of memory: cannot allocate 1073741824-byte block (1077805056 in use) fatal error: out of memory

The error occurs in the line "result.Write(buf[:n])". I am using Windows 10, go version go1.21.6 windows/386, 16 GB RAM, intel core i5-11400

```
import (
    "bytes"
    "io"
    "os"
)

func readFile(filename string) ([]byte, error) {
    f, err := os.Open(filename)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    defer f.Close()
    var result bytes.Buffer
    buf := make([]byte, 4096)
    for {
        n, err := io.ReadAtLeast(f, buf, 1)
        if err != nil {
            if err == io.EOF {
                break
            }
            return nil, err
        }
        result.Write(buf[:n])
    }
    return result.Bytes(), nil
}
```

I want to read my file and get a byte slice to pass it on.

Comment: `windows/386` is the 32-bit version of the Go compiler, that surely has limited memory management capabilities (maybe around 2-4 GB). You should definitely use the 64-bit version! Download and use the amd64 release. Also you shouldn't keep such amount of data in memory, you should write that into a file instead!

Comment: Try to work not on the whole file at once. Stuff like merging database files seldomly requires all data in RAM all the time.

Comment: @icza, I've taken a liberty to cite a part of your comment in my answer; hope you do not object :-)

Comment: @kostix Never, especially if credit is given / source cited.

Comment: As others pointed out you probably shouldn't read the entire file at once, but I'd still like to point out that you're reinventing [os.ReadFile](https://pkg.go.dev/os#ReadFile) here, and in a way that uses more memory than necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, what @icza said:

> `windows/386` is the 32-bit version of the Go compiler, that surely has limited memory management capabilities (maybe around 2-4 GB). You should definitely use the 64-bit version! Download and use the `amd64` release.

I would add that your approach to read a file is a bit naive: `bytes.Buffer` is just a fancy convenient wrapper around `[]byte`, it maintains a single contiguous slice of bytes, which means it has to *reallocate* its memory periodically while you're keeping `Write`-ing into it–basically performing `slice = append(slice, newData)`. This approach has two properties:

- `append` *overallocates* memory in an attempt to not perform true reallocation on each call to `append` in a row on the same data.
- Reallocation means allocating a new chunk of memory which is larger than the existing one then copying over the memory form the existing chunk. This means if you have a slice of 1 GiB and try to append a 4 KiB chunk to it, `append` would allocate a *new* array of size 1 GiB plus some megabytes then copy over that one gigabyte worth of data. *Then* the old array becomes garbage which is not yet collected and from the point of view of the OS kernel, it appears to be a still allocated memory. So, naturally, when you're close to the full limit of how much a 32-bit program can allocate on a given 32-bit architecture, another attempt to reallocate a big enough slice might legitimately fail.

One approach to work around this issue is to call `Stat` on an opened file, then allocate a slice the size of the reported file size, and then use `io.ReadFull` to read the whole file in one go. Or you can just use `os.ReadFile`.

Another, better, approach is to just not "slurp" the whole file into memory if that is not needed: it's way better to open the source file, the destination file and then call `io.Copy` on both.

From your question, it's not clear whether this approach is viable or not. If you need to

> *merge* dbf files

(emphasis mine) you might want to keep in memory only the *keys* of the data records, then perform merge on these keys–which basically would result in a data structure which maps keys to the file the data for a particular key has to be taken from, and then you would iterate over the keys, reading their data and writing it to the resulting file as you go.

If, instead, you have used an unfortunate term to actually mean *concatenating* two data files, then two plain calls to `io.Copy` would do the trick.

One last note: you might want to wrap the source file(s) with `bufio.Reader` to have decent read performance; using `bufio.Writer` with the resulting file could help as well. Without this, the I/O performance might surprise you.

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates that the program is trying to allocate a 1.5 GB block of memory, which exceeds the available memory on your system (16 GB). This is because the `bytes.Buffer` is trying to grow to accommodate the entire file contents, which is not feasible for large files.

Note that this is particularly problematic because the `windows/386` architecture has a 32-bit address space, which limits the maximum amount of memory that can be addressed to 4 GB. Attempting to allocate more memory than this can lead to errors such as "out of memory" or "cannot allocate memory block".

To fix this issue, you can use a streaming approach to read the file, instead of loading the entire file into memory. One way to do this is to use the `io.Reader` interface and the `io.Copy` function to copy the contents of the file to a new byte slice.

Here's an updated version of your readFile function that uses streaming:

```golang
func readFile(filename string) ([]byte, error) {
    f, err := os.Open(filename)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    defer f.Close()

    var b bytes.Buffer
    _, err = io.Copy(&b, f)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return b.Bytes(), nil
}
```

In this version, we create a new `bytes.Buffer` and use the `io.Copy` function to copy the contents of the file to the buffer. The `io.Copy` function will stream the contents of the file, chunk by chunk, without loading the entire file into memory.